# Is it possible for subclass to enhance super's method without overriding?

Tags: java, inheritance

Consider the following set up:

```
 - SomeFilter extends Filter
 - Filter implements Runnable
 - Filter provides run() implementation
```

Is there a way to make `SomeFilter` use it's `super`'s `run()` and bit more?

The logic inside `run()` is generic enough for

```
- MyFilter extends Filter
- MyOtherFilter extends Filter
```

but is not for `SomeFilter`, that would like to use it's super's `run()` and add a few extra lines of code to handle it's own specific case?

Is there  way to do it, **other then** for `SomeFilter` to override `run()` altogether?

Comment: Assuming that you know how to invoke methods in the parent class, (using super), why are you looking for a way "other than overriding"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Inside SomeFilter:

```
@Override
public void run(){
   super.run();
   // custom run code

}
```

Comment: If this is the same "run" that comes in from the Runnable interface, then it can't be private.

Comment: Something is not adding up.  (1) Filter implements `java.lang.Runnable`.  (2) `java.lang.Runnable` has a public run method.  How could `super.run` not be visible?